# Directly save plot to image without using getframe in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have the following code to retrieve boundary of an image using `bwboundaries()`.

The issue is that I need to save the resulting plot lines directly to an image without plotting it first. Currently I am using the `getframe()` function to save the plot to an image. However that is taking up a lot of processing time since I have to plot the boundary image each time for every input image.

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
 %GET 8-NEIGHBOURHOOD BOUNDARIES
    [B,L,N] = bwboundaries(z,'noholes');

 %PLOT THE BOUNDARY FIGURE FOR EACH WORD
    f = figure;
    set(f, 'Visible', 'off');
    hold on;
    for k=1:length(B),
        boundary = B{k};
        if(k > N)
            plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
        else
            plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);
        end
    end
    hold off;
    set(gca, 'visible', 'off');
    F = getframe(gcf);
    [X, Map] = frame2im(F);
    close(gcf);

 %CONVERT EACH BOUNDARY PLOT TO AN IMAGE
    if isempty(Map)
        rgb = X;
    else
        rgb = ind2rgb(X,Map);
    end
```

I had the idea that since each line is being plotted in a loop, I could start appending each line to an image matrix. But I don't how to go about implementing this.
The X and Y coordinates for each line is `boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1)` if I'm not mistaken.

---

Looking at Fletch's reply, I tried the following modification in the code:

```
 %GET 8-NEIGHBOURHOOD BOUNDARIES
    [B,L,N] = bwboundaries(z,'noholes');

    rgb = ones(100, 100, 3);

    %PLOT THE BOUNDARY FIGURE FOR EACH WORD
    for k=1:length(B),
        boundary = B{k};
        if(k > N)
            rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];
        else
            rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];
        end
    end
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in random (line 107)
            rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];
```

`B` is a cell array and B{2} for instance, has the following data:
2931    168
2931    169
2931    170
2931    171
2931    172
2931    173
2931    174
2931    175
2931    176
2931    177
2931    176
2931    175
2931    174
2931    173
2931    172
2931    171
2931    170
2931    169
2931    168

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, you can use `insertShape` to draw the lines directly into the image.

Comment: I need the resulting final image, since I don't have any previous image to begin with.

Comment: @Fletch I checked and tried your edit, didn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you're trying to draw a image using a line coordinates. Consider:

1. You have the lines X and Y coordinate vector (I'm assuming the coordinates are integers).
2. An image is just an set of RBG vectors assigned to a 2D matrix.

So, what you should be able to do is make a blank m-n-3 matrix and change the RBG value at each X-Y point on the image matrix that corresponds to a point in the line's X-Y set. Like so:

```
%// First, set the size of your image. (you'll need to customize this)
[imageSizeX, imageSizeY, ~] = size(yourInputImage);

%// Next, build a matrix corresponding to an all-white image. 
imageMat = ones(imageSizeX, imageSizeY, 3);

%// Then, "black out" each pixel which corresponds to a point on your line.
imageMat(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];

%// At this point imageMat IS and image, and you can do anything with it that you would do with an image
%// Finally, save the matrix as an image. This step is optional.
imwrite(imageMat, 'yourImage.png');
```

This is a relatively efficient (and quite clever, I think) way to solve your problem. Let me know if you need more explanation, or if it doesn't work the way you expect. I'll do my best to help. Good luck!

---

**Edit:** Try this. Note, that you need to supply the real variable name of `yourInputImage`. This should resolve the dimension mismatch. If you get an `index exceeds matrix dimensions` error, `flip boundary(i,2)` and `boundary(i,1)`.

```
[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(z,'noholes');
[imageSizeX, imageSizeY, ~] = size(yourInputImage);
rgb = ones(imageSizeX, imageSizeY, 3);

%PLOT THE BOUNDARY FIGURE FOR EACH WORD
for k=1:length(B),
    boundary = B{k};
    if(k > N)
        for(ii= 1:size(boundary, 2) )
            rgb(boundary(ii,2), boundary(ii,1), :) = [0 1 0];
        end
    else
        for(ii= 1:size(boundary, 2) )
            rgb(boundary(ii,2), boundary(ii,1), :) = [1 0 0];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Also, running the code gives me the following error:
    `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`
    `Error in random (line 107)`
        `rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];`

Comment: This looks perfect! But the part I don't get is that I have the start and end coordinates. How do I "black out" every other point between these two points to form the actual line? That is what plot() was doing for me, I guess.

Comment: Hmmm. We must have different assumptions about what `boundary` is. Could you edit your question and post the contents of boundary? The dimension mismatch is caused by either a mis-preallocated rbg, or bad indexing. If you could, also post your method for building the matrix `rgb`. We'll get you an answer.

Comment: The error (`rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1)) = [0 0];`) doesn't match the posted code `rgb(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), :) = [0 0 0];`. You may just need to save your function and rerun. Also, I'll still need to see what's in `boundary`.

Comment: there you go. Updated again.

Comment: Ah! I found it!  You made `rbg` 100x100. You have to make it the size of the original image you were analyzing. So, if that image was 1000000x1000000 pixels, then you need `rgb = ones(1000000, 1000000, 3);` Use `size()` on your original image to get the dimensions you need.

Comment: I would need to initialize `rgb` as a 3-D array right? Since I am equating that to `[0 0 0]`?

Comment: Right, it's not the *number* of dimensions, but the *size* of the first two dimension. If that doesn't work, you'll need to loop through the length of boundary and assign each point therein individually. I'll post some code later, if you don't have it by then. I build a toy system on my machine to do this, and it works, so we just need to get your code working like mine.

Comment: Please help me out with this. Would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: please look into http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Error_Messages#Assignment_errors for an explanation on my error.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I am getting discrete points, not complete lines as needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought it would. I can't understand what you mean by "line". A series of contiguous, indivisible, discrete points **is** a line, by definition. So, if boundary indeed looks like the example you posted, you do have a line. There is not other meaning of line that I know of. If you expected some other output, please post an image of your results to your question, and describe how your desired output is different.

Comment: Let me give you an output of what I have with `plot()`. That would make things clear, I am guessing.

http://s1.postimg.org/7uf2e0x4f/wordboundary.jpg

Comment: please check the image I have shared.

Comment: I can't follow that link. Please post your image directly on your question. Furthermore, I need more than just your output from plot. I need your output from the algorithm I developed as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55714/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-fletch).